# Pay Dialog Error: This method isn't supported for this display type

Tags: facebook, windows-phone-7, mobile, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-credits

I'm trying to test purchasing with Facebook credits on a WP7 device, but I'm getting the following message:

> API Error Code: 3
>
> API Error Description: Unknown method
>
> Error Message: This method isn't supported for this display type.

I'm launching the dialog with the following:

```
var obj = {
method: 'pay',  
order_info: 'item1',
purchase_type: 'item'
};

FB.ui(obj, callback);
```

It works fine in a desktop browser.

I know mobile credit purchases aren't supported on the iPhone, but the documentation seems to indicate that it should work on any other mobile platform: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/credits/

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I've submitted a bug report. If anyone else is experiencing this problem, please go ahead and vote it up: http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/129304323862687